# json.dumps unorderable types when using None as a key

Tags: python, json

When calling `json.dumps` on an object that contains a dictionary with a `None` and `str` type, how do I have it sort the results without throwing an exception? I'm trying it with `sort_keys=True` but that threw a `TypeError`. I don't care how `None` and `bar` are sorted relative to each other as long as it's consistent from run-to-run.

```
import json
foo = {None: 7, 'bar': 8}
json.dumps(foo)
```

which prints

```
'{"bar": 8, "null": 7}'
```

But then

```
json.dumps(foo, sort_keys=True)
```

prints

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
   File "C:\Program Files\Python35\lib\json\__init__.py", line 237, in dumps
     **kw).encode(obj)
   File "C:\Program Files\Python35\lib\json\encoder.py", line 198, in encode
     chunks = self.iterencode(o, _one_shot=True)
   File "C:\Program Files\Python35\lib\json\encoder.py", line 256, in iterencode
     return _iterencode(o, 0)
 TypeError: unorderable types: NoneType() < str()
```

Comment: The `"null"` hints at something important. You cannot have non-strings in JSON data. If you do, then it is not JSON serialisable. In this case, python attempts to convert the None to "null" (that's bad, I think it should error out), but it draws the line at _sorting_.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ I think that's solid enough to be an answer (unless this is a dupe, but I couldn't find one that specifically addresses `sort_keys`).

Comment: Ah, that's an excellent point. So what I"m really trying to do is get a pretty-print of an object. I usually use `json.dumps(obj, indent=4, sort_keys=True)`. The JSON itself it not important to me. I removed the `indent=4` for my minimum reproducible example, but turns out it was actually relevant. Is there a better way to pretty print like that in Python without worrying about the constraints of JSON?

Comment: Maybe `json.dumps({str(k):  v for k, v in foo.items()}, sort_keys=True)` does what you want?

Comment: that works except that foo is usually a more complex structure. Where I actually hit this it was about 3 nested dictionaries deep

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out a key of `null` is invalid JSON. Clearly, `json.dumps(...)` converts `None` keys to the string `'null'` before returning, but presumably `json.dumps(..., sort_keys=True)` does the sorting *before* the conversion to a string.

One solution I found that allowed both sorting and displaying the structure in JSON is to convert it to JSON first, then sort the keys, like so:

```
import json

foo = {None: 7, 'bar': 8}
# {'bar': 8, None: 7}

foo_json = json.dumps(foo)
# '{"bar": 8, "null": 7}'

foo_prime = json.loads(foo_json)
# {'null': 7, 'bar': 8}

foo_sorted = json.dumps(foo_prime, sort_keys=True)
# '{"bar": 8, "null": 7}'
```

This does change the key (from `None/null` to `'null'`) but does so consistently.